# Including connection file to a class "Undefined variable conn"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have two php files one of which is a class. I am trying to include the file that has the `$conn` variable which connects to the database. The problem is that I am getting this errors:

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /home/yuran/public_html/avec/DatabaseContent.php on line 20

 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/yuran/public_html/avec/DatabaseContent.php on line 20
```

Here is the code:

connection.php

```
<?php
    require_once('constants.php');

    try{
    //Create a database connection
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";"."dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    } catch(PDOException $pe){
        die("Could not connect to the database ".DB_NAME.": ".$pe->getMessage());
    }

?>
```

DatabaseContent.php

```
<?php
include('inc/conn/connection.php');

class DatabaseContent{

public function fetchAllRows($table, $rowOrder, $direction){
        $this->sql .= "ORDER BY :roworder :direction";
        $q = $conn->prepare($this->sql);
        $q->execute(array(':table'=>$table, 'roworder'=>$rowOrder, ':direction'=>$direction));
        $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $q;
    }
```

Comment: Just pass the connection variable as parameter?!

Comment: Your problem is that `$conn` is not known to the class you're trying to use it in. Pass it in as a parameter to the function and use it there.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, so that means that I won't have to include the connection.php file to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Including the file outside the class won't work.

You can pass the `$con` variable as a parameter, since you also can't include the file inside the function.

So change your

```
public function fetchAllRows($table, $rowOrder, $direction)
```

to

```
public function fetchAllRows($table, $rowOrder, $direction,$con)
```

and when you are calling the function, simply pass the connection link as a parameter in the function call.